# List value updates immediately sometime but need refresh othertime

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am new to AngularJS, I am facing a problem updating a list

```
MyApp.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, MainService) {
    var getSomething = function() {
        MainService.getSomething().then(function(data) {
            $scope.something = data.data;
        }, function(error) {

        });
    };

    getSomething();

    $scope.addSomething = function() {
        if($scope.somename) {
            MainService.addSomething($scope.somename);
            $scope.somename = "";
            getSomething();
        }
    }
});
```

Now after adding something to my database I call a function `getSomething()`, which gets new list of some data from service. My Problem is sometimes it updates the variable `$scope.something` other time I need to refresh the page.

**Edited :**
I tried to print `data.data` it prints updated data, I think there is something related to digest cycle.

Comment: Can you share its code `MainService.addSomething()` code?

Comment: Did you take a look into the network logs from your browser? Maybe your request just got stucked?

Comment: The code of Main Service is :

`factory.getSomething = function() {
   content = {'action' : 'getAll'};
   return $http({
    method : 'POST',
    url    : '../api/controllers/SomeAPICtrl.php',
    data   :  content,
    headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
   })
  }`

Comment: @fubbe I checked network log but there is no problem.